# Returning an object with a promise (resolve, reject)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a promise, from which I want to convert a webkitGetAsEntry fileobject to a regular File object.

```
var getAsFile = async function(fileEntry) {
    try {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => fileEntry.file(resolve, reject));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

However, after alot of changes to my code, I would really want to return an object in which I have a path to the file as well. I.e.

```
var getAsFile = async function(fileEntry) {
    try {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => return { 'file': fileEntry.file(resolve, reject), 'filepath': fileEntry.fullPath};);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

When the following promise is resolved, only the file is returned and not the object.

```
getAsFile(entries[i]).then(function (file) {
    //Can only get the file, and not file.filepath
})
```

What fundamental knowledge about promises am I missing here, and how do I achieve returning an object with file and filepath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the object to the `resolve` function:

```
var getAsFile = function(fileEntry) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => fileEntry.file(
        file => resolve({file, filepath: fileEntry.fullPath}),  
        reject
    ));
}
```

Note that it is not necessary to declare that function as `async` since you return a promise and don't use `await`.

The error handling should happen at the place where this function is called.

Comment: just for the record, the `try / catch` is not really necessary here. `return new Promise(callback)` will never error in that sense, even if the callback itself errors. You're safe to just return the promise without a try / catch

Comment: @TKoL, indeed, I didn't address that, but have now cleaned the answer in that respect.